# Access JSON lumps in metafields with Shopify Liquid templates

Tags: json, shopify, template-engine, liquid

I was wondering if anyone knew if I can access JSON in Liquid such as the example below.

I have created a metafield for the suppliers page with the namespace `suppliers_details`, with the key `suppliers` and the value:

```
{
  name: "Supplier Name One",
  address: "Supplier Address One"
},
{
  name: "Supplier Name Two",
  address: "Supplier Address Two"
}
```

In the template I have:

```
{% assign suppliers = page.metafields.suppliers.suppliers %}
{% for supplier in suppliers %}
  <p>{{ supplier.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ supplier.address }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work as I can't change the data into a format the the template can use to iterate through, is there a way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now supported and is a game changer! Shopify released a new metafield format type called "json_string" that lets you directly access the value of each node via normal liquid dot notation. I know this will make EVERYONE'S life easier. Taken from the documentation (https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/metafield):

[image: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/metafield]

Here was one of the initial posts from a Shopify developer on the Shopify forums that may help: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/api-announcements/t/new-json_string-value-type-for-metafield-object-540896

Answer (score 10):

Shopify has since deprecated the "json_string" metafield and supplied a "json" metafield option.

To access the data using dot notation, you need to use .value after the key.

For example, if I have this JSON:

```
{
  name: "Supplier Name One",
  address: "Supplier Address One"
},
{
  name: "Supplier Name Two",
  address: "Supplier Address Two"
}
```

I would access it like this:

```
{% assign suppliers = page.metafields.suppliers.suppliers.value %}
{% for supplier in suppliers %}
  <p>{{ supplier.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ supplier.address }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is now the best answer, after changes they made in late 2021.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to parse a JSON using Liquid or at least not a default way.

You can write some code to split it into parts, but you won't be able to chain the objects:

```
{% capture string %}{name:"Supplier Name One",address:"Supplier Address One"},{name:"Supplier Name Two",address:"Supplier Address Two"}{% endcapture %}

{% assign jsplit = string | replace: '},{', '@@' %}
{% assign jsplit = jsplit | replace: '{' %}
{% assign jsplit = jsplit | replace: '}' %}
{% assign jsplit = jsplit | split: '@@' %}

{% for json in jsplit %}
  {% assign splitByComma = json | split: ',' %}
  {% for comma in splitByComma %}
    {% assign splitByDots = comma | split: ':' %}
    <p>{{ splitByDots[1] }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You will get the wanted result, but not the same way you imagined it.

The best approach will be to pass the string to Javascript, parse it there and populate the DOM via JS.

Comment: Thanks. And there's no functionality using Shopify to include YAML files and parse them (as Jekyll allows)?

Comment: No of course not. Why would Shopify use a format that has no analog in the browser? JSON is the standard data structure for client side computing in the browser, so you get JSON. And since JSON is a string, we are lucky that we store them in metafields, and then render the data therein with our trusty JS.

Comment: One problem with building it with JS is SEO. If this is a menu or something that needs to be SEO friendly building it with JS can affect your SEO.

Comment: dude... this is legit the craziest and absolutely only way to solve this problem. my mouth is watering. my project is complete. I have 200 products all with unique attributes but not variants and i only want the unique information displayed in the confirmation email. so i tag my products, and parse the json tags before sending the receipt. so epic. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is working now, below is my json , it is product metafield & valueType is json string

```
[ 
   { 
      "question":"hello this is question",
      "answer":"Hello This is answer"
   },
   { 
      "question":"hello this is question2 ",
      "answer":"Hello This is answer 2"
   }
]
```

Blow is liquid code

```
{% assign qas = product.metafields.manifester.product_qa %} // product.metafields.{namespace}.{key}

{% for qa in qas %}
  <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;">
    <p> {{ qa.question }} </p>
    <p style="font-weight:bold"> {{ qa.answer }} </p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is this working for new type "json" as "json_string" has been deprecated?